# why navbar button slides down when clicked on it?

Tags: html, css

Hej, can anybody help me with the problem with menu. When I'm clicking on the link, it's not opening you can see the problem here http://hostryy.5gbfree.com/INDEX.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added this styles.

```
.mail a:link, a:visited, a:active {
   position: relative;
   top: 40px !important; <= You need to remove this line
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   font-family: "raleway", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

Go to `style.css` on 207 line remove this or make it 0

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem)) I've been strugling with it a lot.